# I ensure database that has image and the database connect is correct ,but I cannot display the image

Tags: php, mysql, image

My display code is :

```
 <?php
 include "file_constants.php";
 // just so we know it is broken
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 // some basic sanity checks
 if(isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
     //connect to the db
     $link = mysql_connect("$host", "$user", "$pass")
     or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());

     // select our database
     mysql_select_db("$db") or die(mysql_error());

     // get the image from the db
     $sql = "SELECT image FROM test_image WHERE id=" .$_GET['id'] . ";";

     // the result of the query
     $result = mysql_query("$sql") or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());

     // set the header for the image
     header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

     echo mysql_result($result, 0);
     // close the db link
     mysql_close($link);
 }
 else {
     echo 'Please use a real id number';
 }
?>
```

I ensure database that has image and the database connect is correct.
I can upload image from php to phpmyadmin (MYSQL).
However, I cannot display the image.(http:// /file_display.php?id=1)
Can someone help me to display image in php?? THANK YOU SO MUCH!

The file-insert code:

```
<html>
<head><title>File Insert</title></head>
<body>
<h3>Please Choose a File and click Submit</h3>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action=
"<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000" />
<input name="userfile" type="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<?php

// check if a file was submitted
if(!isset($_FILES['userfile']))
{
    echo '<p>Please select a file</p>';
}
else
{
    try {
    $msg= upload();  //this will upload your image
    echo $msg;  //Message showing success or failure.
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    echo 'Sorry, could not upload file';
    }
}

// the upload function

function upload() {
    include "file_constants.php";
    $maxsize = 10000000; //set to approx 10 MB

    //check associated error code
    if($_FILES['userfile']['error']==UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

        //check whether file is uploaded with HTTP POST
        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {    

            //checks size of uploaded image on server side
            if( $_FILES['userfile']['size'] < $maxsize) {  

               //checks whether uploaded file is of image type
              //if(strpos(mime_content_type($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']),"image")===0) {
                 $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
                if(strpos(finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']),"image")===0) {    

                    // prepare the image for insertion
                    $imgData =addslashes (file_get_contents($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']));

                    // put the image in the db...
                    // database connection
                    mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) OR DIE (mysql_error());

                    // select the db
                    mysql_select_db ($db) OR DIE ("Unable to select db".mysql_error());

                    // our sql query
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO test_image
                    (image, name)
                    VALUES
                    ('{$imgData}', '{$_FILES['userfile']['name']}');";

                    // insert the image
                    mysql_query($sql) or die("Error in Query: " . mysql_error());
                    $msg='<p>Image successfully saved in database with id ='. mysql_insert_id().' </p>';
                }
                else
                    $msg="<p>Uploaded file is not an image.</p>";
            }
             else {
                // if the file is not less than the maximum allowed, print an error
                $msg='<div>File exceeds the Maximum File limit</div>
                <div>Maximum File limit is '.$maxsize.' bytes</div>
                <div>File '.$_FILES['userfile']['name'].' is '.$_FILES['userfile']['size'].
                ' bytes</div><hr />';
                }
        }
        else
            $msg="File not uploaded successfully.";

    }
    else {
        $msg= file_upload_error_message($_FILES['userfile']['error']);
    }
    return $msg;
}

// Function to return error message based on error code

function file_upload_error_message($error_code) {
    switch ($error_code) {
        case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
            return 'The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
            return 'The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL:
            return 'The uploaded file was only partially uploaded';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
            return 'No file was uploaded';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR:
            return 'Missing a temporary folder';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE:
            return 'Failed to write file to disk';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION:
            return 'File upload stopped by extension';
        default:
            return 'Unknown upload error';
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The SQL is:

```
create table test_image (
id              int(10)  not null AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name            varchar(25) not null default '',
image           blob        not null
 );
```

The tutorial is http://vikasmahajan.wordpress.com/2010/07/07/inserting-and-displaying-images-in-mysql-using-php/

Comment: Don't want to use `<img>` tag ?

Comment: Oh, I think I want <img> tag

Comment: You can do something like this `<img src="<?php echo $result; ?>" />`Make sure it returns as a single string and not as an array.

Comment: I just know to use 127.0.0.1/phpname.php?id=1 to display image, but it cannot work.

Comment: If you have just copied and pasted all data then It should work.

Answer (score 1):

If you saved just the image name in the database , this will display the image in your HTML

```
<?php
    $result = mysql_query("$sql") or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<img src="www.yourdomain.com/your/directory/"'. $row["image "].'/>';
    }
?>
```

NOTE : Dont need to use the `while` loop if you having only one row

Comment: did u print the $row array? if it contains the image name, then you need to adjust the path as per your directory structure(no need to use the domain name part if you know how to set the directory path)

Comment: I don't know what you mean, but thank you your comment!

Comment: Its simple. is your uploaded images containing directory and your php files containing directory are same?? If else gimme the directory structure, i think i can help you only then

Comment: OH my friend help me to solve this problem, but thank you very much!

Comment: @RX93Gundam Whats the problem now? Is it fixed yet?

Comment: My friend used the other code that was provided by other web site. It can work. Thank you!